# have the last word/ be the last word (in fashion)

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, sentence-translation

What suggestions would colleagues suggest for this English phrase? Example sentences are:-
-Everyone started shouting, trying to have the last word, and the whole meeting just descended into chaos.
-She aleays likes to have the last word in any argument.
The second use of the phrase is to be the best or most modern example of something:
It's a nice enough restaurant and it's very reasonably priced but it's not exactly the last word in style.